# PayPal Plus: Sorry, at the moment no payments can be processed for technical reasons

Tags: paypal

I'm trying to integrate PayPal Plus for Mexico and Brazil and although I successfully create an approval URL when I execute:

```
<div id="ppplus">
</div> 
<script src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/webstatic/ppplusdcc/ppplusdcc.min.js"></script> 
<script>
var ppp = PAYPAL.apps.PPP({ 
  'approvalUrl': 'https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout&token=EC-2S04588163350822V',
  'payerEmail': '***@***.com',
  'payerFirstName': 'Foo',
  'payerLastName': 'Bar',
  'payerPhone': '+55123456789',
  'payerTaxId': '431.587.124-90', // CPF
  'placeholder': 'ppplus',
  'country': 'BR', // BR, MX...
  'collectBillingAddress': false,
  'mode': 'sandbox'
});
</script>
```

I get the following page:
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems your receiving account in sandbox does not belong to a country that can receive PayPal Plus payments.

Create a new PayPal business account for an appropriate country via https://www.paypal.com/signin?intent=developer&returnUri=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.paypal.com%2Fdeveloper%2Faccounts%2F

Once done, create a new REST API App for that account via https://developer.paypal.com/developer/applications